# How to present another view controller inside the didFailNavigation method

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I 'am using a WKWebView and i want to know how to present programmatically if the webview fail to load.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cantConnectNetworkVC") as? CantConnectNetworkVC {
        present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I've tried this but it is not working.

Comment: did you add the *cantConnectNetworkVC* identifier to your storyboard?

Comment: yesI add cantConnectNetworkVC as identifier

Comment: then make sure your viewController is actually on screen before calling  present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil). If not you will get an error in the logs saying "Attempting to present viewcontroller whose view isn't on screen yet"

Comment: Is that your parent controller is presented one or pushed one?

Comment: @Rohi my parent controller is pushed

Comment: check by presenting viewcontroller over navigation controller instead from parent controller.

Comment: @Blisko, Is that helped you?

Comment: @ Blisko, Please accept my answer if it helped you and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Check by presenting viewcontroller over navigation controller instead from parent controller.